# Issues with Grep

Tags: r, subset

I am using grep in order to separate ID's that begin with 1 and 2, as 1 indicates that they are a manager and 2 indicates that they are a worker. This works for the manager calls below, but when I try to use grep for the IDs starting with 2, it doesn't work. My ID variables are prefixed with 1 or 2 and then followed by 9 other random numbers. Does anyone have any idea why grep wouldn't work with 2?

```
#MANAGER CALLS
MANAGERCALLS_BYDATE <- file[, c("ID","CALLEE", "weekday")]
MANAGERCALLS_BYDATE <- subset(MANAGERCALLS_BYDATE, ID == grep("^1.{9}", 
file$ID, value=TRUE))

#WORKER CALLS
WORKERCALLS_BYDATE <-file[, c("ID","CALLEE", "weekday")]
WORKERCALLS_BYDATE <- subset(WORKERCALLS_BYDATE, ID == grep("^2.{9}", 
file$ID, value=TRUE))
```

Comment: Eventually you want `subset(MANAGERCALLS_BYDATE, grepl(...))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out to change the `==` by `%in%`
I suppose that there is just one manager in your data.frame, but several workers. Thats why Manager Calls work and Worker calls not.

```
#WORKER CALLS
WORKERCALLS_BYDATE <-file[, c("ID","CALLEE", "weekday")]
WORKERCALLS_BYDATE <- subset(WORKERCALLS_BYDATE, ID %in% grep("^2.{9}", 
file$ID,value=TRUE))
```